# EntityManager's Connection always returns fals when committing

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to execute a transaction the lowest level possible inside a symfony app:

```
$conn = $this->em->getConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
$success = $conn->commit();
```

but `$success` is always `false`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit` doesn't return a boolean value, It throw an exception if there is something wrong.
To be sure that the transaction success use a try catch like this:

```
try{
    $conn->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: u r right, I was looking at `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::commit` which returns a boolean

Comment: Glad to help you! :)